# Detect Touch Event of Windows Phone on any screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, windows-phone-8, touch, getpixel

Since, I am new to Windows Phone technology ,so I want to detect touch event of Windows phone screen that means if I have touched on any screen on Windows Phone not necessary in application only outside of application (like start screen,settings screen) so can I get that touch event or any pixel information regarding that touch.Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Thanks you.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: ok ,but there is no other way also for accessing any screen outside of application ?

Comment: nopes, that is also not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To protect the privacy of the user, there is no way to globally hook all touch events from an application. You can only react to events within your application.

Further, an application cannot access the screen while other applications are active. That would be a significant privacy hole if an application could record the actions of other applications.

Comment: @user3146084 - if this answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer (and also it's great if you can accept answers on questions you've asked).